# Align hex number next to them

Tags: c++, hex

I need some help for a script. I have hex number like and I need to align next to them, but I have no idea how to solve this with a nice way in c++.

For example I have this array:

```
int test[3]={0x12,0x13,0xab};
```

So and I would like to have this Output:

```
0x1213ab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int test[3] = {0x12,0x13,0xab};

    std::cout << "0x";
    for(auto x : test) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << x;
                  // |           |               |
                  // |           |               v
                  // |           |               Prevents filling blanks
                  // |           v
                  // |           Chooses a field output size of 2
                  // v
                  // Provides hex formatting of integers
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b538f1ef7a7b03)

---

Relevant links from a good [c++ reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/):

- [Input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)
- [Input/output manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Comment: is it possible to transfer the output in an integer?

Comment: @Yann Yes, merely the same using a `std::istream` ans the `std::hex` I/O manipulator. But there are even faster methods, doing a simple copy in memory.